# Open CSV file via VBA (performance)

Tags: excel, vba

Obviously, this question has been asked many times. The normal procedure:

`Workbooks.Open (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Test.csv")`

won't parse the CSV correctly (having many rows in one cell)

Thanks to Lernkurve, I can use his function to get it right: [Opening semicolon delimited CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553888/opening-semicolon-delimited-csv-file-with-vba-in-excel-2000)

```
Sub ImportCSVFile(filepath As String)
Dim line As String
Dim arrayOfElements
Dim linenumber As Integer
Dim elementnumber As Integer
Dim element As Variant

linenumber = 0
elementnumber = 0

Open filepath For Input As #1 ' Open file for input
    Do While Not EOF(1) ' Loop until end of file
        linenumber = linenumber + 1
        Line Input #1, line
        arrayOfElements = Split(line, ";")

        elementnumber = 0
        For Each element In arrayOfElements
            elementnumber = elementnumber + 1
            Cells(linenumber, elementnumber).Value = element
        Next
    Loop
Close #1 ' Close file.
End Sub
```

This however is not fast (I have files with thousands of columns) and my question is:

Is there any native way to open CSV files in Excel with right parsing?

Comment: What is the size of the CSV file (in MB for example) and what is the maximum duration you would like the operation to take?

Comment: around 450 kb /file and around 14 files . since this macro is targeted to be used by ppl who cannot code it must be totally automated and fast so the user does not need to wait.

Comment: if it is 450kb then the function I gave in my answer should open and copy the content of the 14 files in less than 3 sec, possibly less.

Comment: then its perfect. will try it. thank you sir

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Workbooks.Open` does work too.

`Workbooks.Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Temp.csv", Local:=True`

this works/is needed because i use Excel in germany and excel does use "," to separate .csv by default because i use an english installation of windows. even if you use the code below excel forces the "," separator.

`Workbooks.Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Test.csv", , , 6, , , , , ";"`

and `Workbooks.Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Temp.csv", , , 4` +variants of this do not work(!)

why do they even have the delimiter parameter if it is blocked by the Local parameter ?! this makes no sense at all. but now it works.

Answer (score 4):

This function reads a CSV file of 15MB and copies its content into a sheet in about 3 secs.
What is probably taking a lot of time in your code is the fact that you copy data cell by cell instead of putting the whole content at once.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

  copyDataFromCsvFileToSheet "C:\temp\test.csv", ",", "Sheet1"

End Sub

Private Sub copyDataFromCsvFileToSheet(parFileName As String, parDelimiter As String, parSheetName As String)

  Dim data As Variant

  data = getDataFromFile(parFileName, parDelimiter)
  If Not isArrayEmpty(data) Then
    With Sheets(parSheetName)
      .Cells.ClearContents
      .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(data, 1), UBound(data, 2)) = data
    End With
  End If

End Sub

Public Function isArrayEmpty(parArray As Variant) As Boolean
'Returns false if not an array or dynamic array that has not been initialised (ReDim) or has been erased (Erase)

  If IsArray(parArray) = False Then isArrayEmpty = True
  On Error Resume Next
  If UBound(parArray) < LBound(parArray) Then isArrayEmpty = True: Exit Function Else: isArrayEmpty = False

End Function

Private Function getDataFromFile(parFileName As String, parDelimiter As String, Optional parExcludeCharacter As String = "") As Variant
'parFileName is supposed to be a delimited file (csv...)
'parDelimiter is the delimiter, "," for example in a comma delimited file
'Returns an empty array if file is empty or can't be opened
'number of columns based on the line with the largest number of columns, not on the first line
'parExcludeCharacter: sometimes csv files have quotes around strings: "XXX" - if parExcludeCharacter = """" then removes the quotes


  Dim locLinesList() As Variant
  Dim locData As Variant
  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long
  Dim locNumRows As Long
  Dim locNumCols As Long
  Dim fso As Variant
  Dim ts As Variant
  Const REDIM_STEP = 10000

  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  On Error GoTo error_open_file
  Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(parFileName)
  On Error GoTo unhandled_error

  'Counts the number of lines and the largest number of columns
  ReDim locLinesList(1 To 1) As Variant
  i = 0
  Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
    If i Mod REDIM_STEP = 0 Then
      ReDim Preserve locLinesList(1 To UBound(locLinesList, 1) + REDIM_STEP) As Variant
    End If
    locLinesList(i + 1) = Split(ts.ReadLine, parDelimiter)
    j = UBound(locLinesList(i + 1), 1) 'number of columns
    If locNumCols < j Then locNumCols = j
    i = i + 1
  Loop

  ts.Close

  locNumRows = i

  If locNumRows = 0 Then Exit Function 'Empty file

  ReDim locData(1 To locNumRows, 1 To locNumCols + 1) As Variant

  'Copies the file into an array
  If parExcludeCharacter <> "" Then

    For i = 1 To locNumRows
      For j = 0 To UBound(locLinesList(i), 1)
        If Left(locLinesList(i)(j), 1) = parExcludeCharacter Then
          If Right(locLinesList(i)(j), 1) = parExcludeCharacter Then
            locLinesList(i)(j) = Mid(locLinesList(i)(j), 2, Len(locLinesList(i)(j)) - 2)       'If locTempArray = "", Mid returns ""
          Else
            locLinesList(i)(j) = Right(locLinesList(i)(j), Len(locLinesList(i)(j)) - 1)
          End If
        ElseIf Right(locLinesList(i)(j), 1) = parExcludeCharacter Then
          locLinesList(i)(j) = Left(locLinesList(i)(j), Len(locLinesList(i)(j)) - 1)
        End If
        locData(i, j + 1) = locLinesList(i)(j)
      Next j
    Next i

  Else

    For i = 1 To locNumRows
      For j = 0 To UBound(locLinesList(i), 1)
        locData(i, j + 1) = locLinesList(i)(j)
      Next j
    Next i

  End If

  getDataFromFile = locData

  Exit Function

error_open_file:             'returns empty variant
unhandled_error:             'returns empty variant

End Function
```

Comment: Wow this is a lot of code for such a task. i will work through it to fully understand it.


so i guess the answer to my original question is "no, vba does not provide native functions to read csv correctly".

thanks for your effort!

Comment: @assylias is there a way of using your code with Locals=true? its messing up the number formatting for me, delimiter works fine

Comment: The code just reads characters and knows nothing about number formatting - if the file contains formatted numbers (for example 1,000,000 for 1 million), you are better off using another option, like the accepted answer (using Workbooks.Open).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [import text function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-import-wizard-HP010102244.aspx).

Comment: i dont have any problem opening a csv manually (like file->open or your mentioned import text function). only opening csv via VBA code does not work as it should and i need to use VBA.

at least i dont see how i can use this in VBA.

but thx anyway for your help!

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro whilst using the import wizard?

Comment: ok tried it with recording and it worked. but its not dynamic enough tbh. i could improve it but then i could write it from scratch too.
i just dont like autobuilding.

Comment: Writing from scratch will probably be much slower than using built in Excel functions as Excel functions are always much faster. Nothing wrong with using code from the macro recorder, it's good for understanding Excel objects :) - just remember you always have to optimize it

Answer (score 1):

This may help you, also it depends how your `CSV` file is formated.

1. Open your excel sheet & go to menu `Data` > `Import External Data` > `Import Data`.
2. Choose your `CSV` file.
3. Original data type: choose `Fixed width`, then `Next`.
4. It will autmaticall delimit your `columns`. then, you may check the splitted columns in `Data preview` panel.
5. Then `Finish` & see.

Note: you may also go with `Delimited` as Original data type. 
In that case, you need to key-in your delimiting character.

HTH!

Comment: same problem as above. this is not vba coding and i dont favour doing automacros (since it adds more code then necessary in most cases). hope you dont hate me for that! i appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, I'm not able to open a CSV file in Excel. I've found a solution that worked for me in this question [Opening a file in excel via Workbooks.OpenText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742443/opening-a-file-in-excel-via-workbooks-opentext)

That question helped me to figure out a code that works for me. The code looks more or less like this:

```
Private Sub OpenCSVFile(filename as String)
    Dim datasourceFilename As String
    Dim currentPath As String

    datasourceFilename = "\" & filename & ".csv"
    currentPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=currentPath & datasourceFilename, _
                       Origin:=xlWindows, _
                       StartRow:=1, _
                       DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                       TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
                       ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
                       Tab:=False, _
                       Semicolon:=False, _
                       Comma:=True, _
                       Space:=False, _
                       Other:=False, _
                       FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), _
                       DecimalSeparator:=".", _
                       ThousandsSeparator:=",", _
                       TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

At least, it helped me to know about lots of parameters I can use with `Workbooks.OpenText` method.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes all the solutions with Workbooks.open is not working no matter how many parameters are set.
For me, the fastest solution was to change the List separator in Region & language settings.
Region window / Additional settings... / List separator.

If csv is not opening in proper way You probly have set ','  as a list separator. Just change it to ';'  and everything is solved.
Just the easiest way when "everything is against You" :P

Answer (score 0):

I just solve (my) problem by setting the *Local* parameter in the `Workbook.Open` method like this:

```
xtrct_wb = Workbooks.Open(filePath, Local:=True)
```

Every information is then in its proper column. Hope it works for you as well.