# How can I load a csv as a sheet of the current workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I load a csv as a sheet of the current workbook in Excel-vba 2007 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open csv file via VBA (performance)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564908/open-csv-file-via-vba-performance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you would need to save it as a csv file. Something like this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="c:\whatever.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa167688%28v=office.10%29.aspx) for more on how to use the SaveAs method.

Is this what you're after?

EDIT

Or if what you're after is to import a csv file like Jerry answered but with VBA, then I believe you use the [OpenText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195814%28v=office.11%29.aspx) method.

```
Workbooks.OpenText FileName:="c:\whatever.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use the **Data > Import data > (choose file) > import options > [x] New Worksheet**