# Import semicolon separated CSV file using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have a problem with opening .csv files with Excel by VBA code. I have data organised like:

```
Number;Name;Price1;Price2;City 
1234;"John Smith";"1,75 EUR";"2,15 EUR";"New Mexico" 
3456;"Andy Jahnson";"12,45 EUR";"15,20 EUR";London 
3456;"James Bond";"42,34 EUR";"9,20 EUR";Berlin
```

When I open this file manually by Excel from Windows Explorator, everything looks fine, all values are separated correctly. It looks like that:

[image: Example1]

When I try to open this by VBA, using

```
Workbooks.Open fileName:=strPath & "thisFile.csv"
```

data is separated by commas, so it looks like that:

[image: Example2]

The same wrong result pops out when I am using OpenText function

```
Workbooks.OpenText filename:=strPath & "thisFile.csv", DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False
```

and when I try use solution from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553888/opening-semicolon-delimited-csv-file). Any ideas?

Comment: What version of excel are you using?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I hope you are using something newer than Excel 2000. This is what I experience with Excel 2016 on a machine with **German format settings**: Apparently the `Workbooks.Open` options for delimiters (`Format` and `Delimiter`) are only applied when you open a `.txt` file. If `Local` is set to `False` (the default value), the file will be opened with the VBA language settings, using a comma as delimiter. Setting `Local:=True` will prevent this so

```
Workbooks.Open FileName:=strPath & "thisFile.csv", Local:=True
```

should work for you. If you rename your file to `.txt`, you can use the `Format` and `Delimiter` options:

```
Workbooks.Open FileName:=strPath & "thisFile.txt", Format:=4 'Format = 4 is semicolon delimited
Workbooks.Open FileName:=strPath & "thisFile.txt", Format:=6, Delimiter:=";" 'Format = 6 is custom delimited
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx) for more details
However this will mess up your decimal numbers, see my edit.

---

**Edit:** I misread the documentation. The `Format` and `Delimiter` options are actually only applied when using a `.txt` file and not `.csv` (even the `.OpenText` method behaves that way).

If you want to make sure it opens on a machine with different format settings the only solution I have right now is to rename it to `.txt` and use

```
Workbooks.OpenText FileName:=strPath & "thisFile.txt", DataType:=xlDelimited, Semicolon:=True, DecimalSeparator:=",", ThousandsSeparator:="."
```