# Search through loaded csv file with ; as the delimiter

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I loaded a csv file as a 2-D array to memory with following code:

```
Sub readcsv()
Dim wbCSV As Workbook
Dim Data As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\File.csv")

With wbCSV
    Data = .Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value
    .Close
End With

End Sub
```

next step i want to search through the data and pick some. the point is that I want to do so without opening the csv itself. is there any way to search through the loaded array? I also know i-j of the intrested data in the csv. The csv uses ; as delimiter. with this code

```
data(i,j)
```

I expect to have the element in the i-j cell but it returns the nonsense string. So the question is, does vba recognise the ; as delimiter when the file is loaded in this way? or i need to arrange the loaded data into a form of a matrix and then call a specific cell?

update:

I have found that

```
data(i,j)
```

returns strange string because vba considers , as the delimiter. So for example when in the 5th row I have a;b;1,2345;c data(5,2) returns 2345;c

thanks

Comment: "I also know i-j of the intrested data in the csv. so I may even do not need to search through the array." - then it seems you've solved your own question?

Comment: If you know i-j of the data, refer to `data(i,j)`

Comment: "without opening the csv" in your next step? Confusing, since you just loaded it in your previous step. Maybe just unlucky phrasing.

Comment: @bigben i just need the access to a specific element of that array.

Comment: @jvdv i mean without browing the csv into excel.

Comment: You can open the CSV file as a text file using File I/O, loop through the data line by line until you find what you are looking for, and then close the file.

Comment: Are you talking about a [random-access file](https://www.engram9.info/excel-2002-vba-xml-asp/working-with-random-access-files.html)?

Comment: @Applecore how can I advance through the cells? does it recognise separator in the original csv?

Comment: What do you mean by "nonsense string"? Unless it is a string with many semicolons, an inability to use the delimiter is unlikely to be the problem.

Comment: Please post a sample of the data file, and also an indication of which piece of data you will be wanting to extract.

Comment: @Applecore An example is added

Comment: @JohnColeman Explanation is added in Update

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import semicolon separated CSV file using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890471/import-semicolon-separated-csv-file-using-vba)

Answer (score 0):

You can open the CSV file as a text file using File I/O, loop through the data line by line until you find what you are looking for, and then close the file

Comment: what is File I/O?